# input part of url to load url

Tags: html, url, input

My goal is to have an input box on a page so that when a word is inputed it will send the user to that part of the website.

For example;

If the user enters the word `banana` and presses `GO` button, the page `www.mysite.com/banana` is loaded

If they enter `apple` it goes to `www.mysite.com/apple` etc

Could anyone show me the neatest way of doing this? Or at least point me to somewhere that could teach me - I am still fairly new to HTML and I am struggling to succesfully search this to find an answer.

(I also need to go to a default `this page does not exist` for inputs that do not find a page, but thats a follow on problem)

Comment: Have you tried any of the 3 answers yet?

Answer (score 0):

By adding the text and URL you can redirect the user.

```
<input type="text" id="search_page" onclick="searchTextPage();" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function searchTextPage(){    
       var searchText = $(#search_page").val();
       window.location = window.location + '/' + searchText;   
    }
</script>
```

For rescue the page, you have to put some condition about the searching the text.

Comment: The question tags don't specify he's using jQuery.

Comment: + Your `oldLocation` variable is never used, and `newLocation` is never declared/initialized.

Comment: @Dreamonic : Thanks for the feedback. I made the updation.

Comment: You're still using jQuery.

Comment: thanks, my javascript skills are pretty limited but I will give it a try and see how it goes

Answer (score 0):

For the textbox you can just use:

```
<input type="text" name="something" size="50" id="naam" />
<input type="submit" value="Send">
```

Then you could use the PHP `header` function to redirect:

```
<?php
if( $_POST)
{

$text   = $_POST['something'];

header("Refresh: 0;url=www.mysite.com/$text");

}
?>
```

Also be sure that the header must be invoked before any output is made. Otherwise the call fails. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8028987/2134785) answer for more info.

Comment: Thanks for this, it makes sense to me and looks fairly straight forward, I will give it a try tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Here's sample HTML:

```
<form action="javascript:void(0);" onsubmit="goToURL();">
    <input id="urlInput" type="text" />
    <input id="urlSubmit" type="submit" value="Go to URL"/>
</form>
```

And JavaScript:

```
function goToURL() {
    var urlInput = document.getElementById("urlInput").value;
    window.location += "/" + urlInput;
}
```

Then (if you're using a server using a web.xml), specify your error page in there:

```
<error-page>
    <location>/general-error.html</location>
</error-page>
```

And if you want to tackle 404's in particular, use this in your `error-page`:

```
<error-code>404</error-code>
```

**Note: I didn't verify if this works.**

Comment: thanks, that seems pretty clear - I will give this a try tomorrow and let you know how it goes